# Kinetic JS resizing canvas/images

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I'm resizing the Kinetic canvas when the window resizes with JS/CSS to reduces the sprites proportionally. The sprites have click events binded to them.

My problem is that while the sprites resize correctly their click area remains fixed at their original x/y coordinates.

It seems once Kinetic draws a sprite to the screen it's fixed to it's initial x/y coordinate.

Is there a way to redraw the sprites and their click coordinates when I resize the window?

Comment: Can we see your KineticJS code and also your resize code?

Answer (score 0):

**KineticJS allows for a custom hit region.**

You could create a custom hit region for your newly sized and newly positioned sprites.

Here's some **untested** code:

First, add some properties to your sprite that define its hit region:

```
sprite1.hitX=sprite1.x;
sprite1.hitY=sprite1.y;
sprite1.hitWidth=30;
sprite1.hitHeight=30;
```

Then define a custom hit region function for your sprite:

```
drawHitFunc: function(canvas) {
  var context = canvas.getContext();
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(this.hitX,this.hitY,this.hitWidth,this.hitHeight);
  canvas.fillStroke(this);
}
```

When you resize the canvas, alter the sprite's hit properties accordingly:

```
function resizeSpriteHitRegion(sprite,scalingFactor){
    sprite.hitX*=scalingFactor;
    sprite.hitY*=scalingFactor;
    sprite.hitWidth*=scalingFactor;
    sprite.hitHeight*=scalingFactor;
}
```

For example, when you resize the canvas to 50% of original size:

```
resizeSpriteHitRegion(sprite1,0.50);
```

This is what is might look like when put together:

```
var sprite1 = new Kinetic.Sprite({
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  image: theSun,
  animation: 'idle',
  animations: animations,
  frameRate: 5,
  index: 0
});
sprite1.hitX=sprite.x;
sprite1.hitY=sprite.y;
sprite1.hitWidth=30;
sprite1.hitHeight=30;
drawHitFunc: function(canvas) {
  var context = canvas.getContext();
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(this.hitX,this.hitY,this.hitWidth,this.hitHeight);
  canvas.fillStroke(this);
}
```

Again, this code is untested...tweaking may be required.

Good luck in your project!